# Как правильно задать CSS стиль при фокусе?

Tags: css

Я хочу при нажатии на `input`, чтобы `label` поднимался на 20px, при условии что html оставался такой как в примере, менять можно только css. Если бы можно было бы убрать span, то все бы работало, но убирать нельзя.

```css
.contact-form form label input:focus ~ label,
.contact-form form label input:valid ~ label,
.contact-form form label textarea:focus ~ label,
.contact-form form label textarea:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
  <form>
    <div class="section-contacts">
      <label>
        <span><input type="text" name="companyName" required /></span>
        <label>Company Name</label>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span><input type="text" name="phone" required /></span>
        <label>Telephone Number</label>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Никак, в css-селекторах пока нельзя подняться выше по дереву элементов.

Comment: Верно, надо либо менять html, либо подключать js

Comment: А если повесить на инпут с фокусом псевдоэлемент, с тем же текстом, что у лейбла на 20px выше, а сам лейбел при фокусе скрывать?

Comment: А как js'ом реализовать?

Comment: Странный у вас код. `label`ом оборачивать `label` не стоит, оборачивать `input` в `span` нет смысле т.к. `input` по умолчанию строчный. Почему html менять нельзя?

Comment: @lexxl, а у меня получилось без js :)

Comment: @АлексейУколов, подняться нельзя, но повлиять-то можно))

Comment: @stackanon, согласен. Кроме того, что input не строчный, а inline-block.

Comment: @Qwertiy найс, интересное решение)

Comment: @АлексейУколов, теперь можно... но только для фокуса :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Переписан только css, разметка полностью сохранена

```css
.section-contacts > label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: margin .3s linear, top .3s linear;
}

input:focus {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
  <form>
    <div class="section-contacts">
      <label>
        <span><input type="text" name="companyName" required /></span>
        <label>Company Name</label>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span><input type="text" name="phone" required /></span>
        <label>Telephone Number</label>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Фокус в шаманстве с перемещением baseline, по которой по умолчанию выровнены inline-block'и. Изменение отступов input'а перемещает baseline, а сам инпут через relative визуально отправляется на старое место. Внешние контейнеры выровнены по центру, высота не изменяется, поэтому они никуда не двигаются. Как-то так :)

Comment: А мне бы Шиманский предьявил что описания нет. В чём секрет?

Comment: @Doofy, в шаманстве с перемещением baseline, по которой по умолчанию выровнены inline-block'и. Изменение отступов input'а перемещает baseline, а сам инпут через relative визуально отправляется на старое место. Внешние контейнеры выровнены по центру, высота не изменяется, поэтому они никуда не двигаются. Как-то так :)

Comment: Да это же читерство) А для чего оборачивают input в span?

Comment: @Doofy, а это не ко мне. Вопрос был - без изменения разметки и без js. Вот я до такого способа додумался. В остальных ответах/комментариях либо эти условия не соблюдаются, либо говорится, что невозможно))) Если придумаешь ещё что-то любопытное, с радостью посмотрю и поставлю плюсик :)

Comment: @Doofy, кстати, этот метод сработал бы даже если бы label был до input'а, а не после.

Comment: На что только не пойдёшь, чтобы угодить заказчику/автору вопроса :)

Comment: @Doofy, всегда же интересно какой-нибудь хак изобрести))))

Comment: Или костыль, потому что ну лучше бы автор сменил нормальную разметку) А так да, попадаются интересные вопросы, над которыми хочется посидеть и подумать

Comment: @Doofy, ага))) Но из ненормального там в первую очередь вложенные label'ы. Span по каким-то причинам может быть нужен. Например, input крайне плохо превращается в table-cell с width 100%.

Comment: А мне казалось input в span'е :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42872/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-doofy).

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю нужно что-то в этом плане

```css
body { margin: 48px; }

label { position: relative; }
label span { position: absolute; left: 6px; }

input:focus + span {
  margin-top: -20px;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
      <form>
         <div class="section-contacts">
             <label>
                <input type="text" name="companyName" required >
                <span>Company Name</span>
             </label>
             <label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" required >
                <span>Telephone Number</span>
             </label>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: *при условии что html оставался такой как в примере*, ну сорян, не понимаю для чего *Company Name* в `label` оборачивать

Answer (score 1):

Появился новый css-селектор [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).
На данный момент он поддерживается в FF 52+ и Chrome 60+. Никаких IE/Edge.

Переписан только css, разметка полностью сохранена.

```css
.section-contacts > label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

label label {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform .3s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

label:focus-within label {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
  <form>
    <div class="section-contacts">
      <label>
        <span><input type="text" name="companyName" required /></span>
        <label>Company Name</label>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span><input type="text" name="phone" required /></span>
        <label>Telephone Number</label>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: эх, пока что даже хромом стабильным нельзя просмотреть )

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, Firefox'ом можно.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с помощью jquery )

```
$('.contact-form form label input').on('focus', function(){
                    parent = $(this).parent();
                    parent = parent.parent();
                    parent.find('.label').addClass('toping');
                });
                 $('.contact-form form label input').on('focusout', function(){
                    if(!$(this).val()){
                        parent = $(this).parent();
                    parent = parent.parent();
                    parent.find('.label').removeClass('toping');
                    }
                });
```